# What does やるな mean when it isn't being used to say "Don't do it"?

Tags: slang

I've often heard it translated as "Not bad," but I haven't able to find anything first hand written about its usage as a compliment. Can anyone tell me more about it?

Comment: you can see 「やるな」 in the top answer

Comment: and this question is related to when it **is** being used to say "don't do it" but it still can be ambiguous because of the colloquial form: [Is the word 「やんな」positive or negative?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33097/is-the-word-%e3%82%84%e3%82%93%e3%81%aa-positive-or-negative)