# Using the word "Unique" in Isolation

Tags: grammar, translation

I am wonder about using the word "unique" in isolation. Would this be written as ユニーク or ユニークな.

Sorry or the lack of explanation. I am looking to print this on a tshirt, and would like it to read "unique". In terms of "something unique". The brand is called 'One of One' and the meaning behind this is to express yourself and be yourself "unique".

I have translated this and come up with results which both include な and those that leave it off of the end of the word.

My question is if I should include the な on the end of the word as I have read that it is normally used to imply negativity when added to verbs. But in this case I am unsure of how to approach a single adjective.
I tried to do some research and could not find a complete answer. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please avoid an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What do you actually want to do? Making a flashcard? Designing a database?

Comment: making a t-shirt silk screen? Putting it on a poster?

Comment: in other words, more information would be good. What are you doing, and what is the purpose of using the word ユニーク? If you could edit your question to include that info, it would help people answer you meaningfully. Did you try looking it up in a dictionary, and get conflicting answers? information like that would help us see your problem more clearly.

Comment: T-シャツに「ユニーク」とプリントされてたら、思わず「ユニクロ」って読んじゃいそうなのは私だけ？

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can just omit な at the end and put only ユニーク on the shirt. This な forms an attributive form, i.e., な is only used to modify the following noun. The concept of ユニーク itself can be conveyed without な. For now, [な after a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33097/5010) is not relevant, either.

(FWIW, ユニーク in Japanese tends to have a bit sarcastic implication. Saying "I am ユニーク" can imply you are a peculiar person. You may be interested in the word [個性](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%80%8B%E6%80%A7), which is a simple noun and have a more positive connotation.)

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Do you think that 個性派 would also be appropriate? As i have seen it to mean "one of a kind" and may be more specific and suited than 個性. 
Thanks

Comment: @Henry Yes 個性派 is also acceptable. Note that it still has a mixed connotation, and does not necessarily mean you are "different" in a good way.