# What is the meaning of 「まちいな」?

Tags: words, dialects, manga

Here is the sentence said by Kansai speaker who was capturing 2 boys who were chasing another guy.

**まちいな**　あんさんたち。

I think the word would mean 待つ with particle な emphasizing the emotion but I would like to know what the exact Japanese standard dialect form of the word really is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In some dialects spoken in the western part of Japan, you can elongate the last vowel of the masu-stem to make an imperative form:

> - 歩きい。 (dialect)　＝　歩け。 Walk.
> - 見い。 (dialect)　＝　見ろ。 Watch.
> - **[待ちい]{LHL}。** (dialect) ＝　[待て]{HL}。 Wait.
> - [食べえ]{LHL}。 (dialect)　＝　[食べろ]{LHL}。 Eat.

(From my personal experience, I feel this is mainly used in Chugoku/Shikoku region, but I may be wrong. See [西日本方言#文法](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A5%BF%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80#.E6.96.87.E6.B3.95))

You can attach various sentence-end particles like な, や, or よ, as usual.

(Attaching な to this kind of imperative may be specific to Osaka dialect. I found this article: [「大阪方言の命令形」に後接する終助詞ヤ・ナ](http://ir.library.osaka-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/11094/4642/1/21-05.pdf) (PDF))

> - すぐ来【き】いや。 (dialect)　＝　すぐ来【こ】いよ。 Come at once.
> - はよう寝えよ。 (dialect)　＝　はやく寝ろよ。 Go to bed now.
> - **[待ちいな]{LHLL}。** (dialect)　＝　[待てよ]{HLL}。 Wait.

Note that you can use な to form *positive* imperative in *standard* Japanese, too. But the last vowel of the masu-form is not elongated in the standard Japanese. Also see the difference in accents.

[Using な in positive instead of negative imperative (e.g. 行きな)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2707/)

> - [待ちな]{LHH}。　＝　[待て]{HL}。
> - [食べな]{LHH}。　＝　[食べろ]{LHL}。

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple transformation into standard Japanese; you were on the right track:

> 待ちなさい、あなたたち。

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Brandon's answer, 「あんさんたち」is rarely used by the younger generation these days. In my line of work I hear it every now and again, but only ever said by the older generation.