# What does the word 「まかせとき」mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, manga, role-language

Here is the sentence said by an old man. (I think that he tried to be the first one to show something before all others.)

> よし先発はわしがいこう まかせとき！

I tried to find the word in online dictionaries but I only found 「まかせとけ」which means 'Leave it to me'. I would like to know whether these two words relate to each other colloquially.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34604/5010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

まかせとき (or まかしとき[な・ん], etc.) is a colloquial/dialectal version of まかせときなさい (from まかせておきなさい) "leave it to me". In the context of manga, this is most likely role language (in this case "geezer speech"—also note the use of わし).

Answer (score 7):

> まかせとき！

I think it's Kansai-ben pronunciation for [任]{まか}せておけ / 任せとけ.
Here in Kyoto/Osaka, we often say things like...

- 「まかしとき(ー)」 or 「まかせとき(ー)」 for 「任せておけ」
- 「おいとき(ー)」 for 「置いておけ」
- 「やめとき(ー)」 for 「やめておけ」
- 「だまっとき(ー)」 for 「黙っておけ」/「黙っていろ」

etc...

Comment: 「Here is Kyoto/Osaka, we often say」ってチョコさんも関西？

Comment: はい、生まれも育ちも京都です。@istrasci さんは大阪にいらしたから、よく関西弁を使われますよね。

Comment: To add to your excellent answer, Kansai-ben allows the imperative (~なさい) to be expressed as the masu-stem with an elongated last vowel (e.g. おきー＞おきー). http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34604/5010 has some useful information including pitch accent.

And the まかし part of まかしとき is a slang form of まかせ(る).