# Meaning of 行かしてもらうから

Tags: grammar, causation, kansai-ben

In 火垂るの墓 there is a scene where the mother says:

> ほな、ひと足先に壕に行かしてもらうからね。

What does 行かしてもらうから mean?

I know usually もらう means to receive / get someone to do something.

I’ve never seen this conjugation of 行く before. Is it a casual form of 行かせて？ where せ—>し？

Answer (score 4):

> ほな、ひと足先に壕に**行かして**もらうからね。

I think it's Kansai dialect. 「ほな」 is Kansai dialect, too. Here in Kyoto (and in Osaka and probably in Kobe as well), we often say:

> 行かせてもらう (in Standard Japanese) ⇒ 行か**し**てもらう (in Kansai-ben)
>   食べさせてもらう ⇒ 食べさ**し**てもらう
>   言わせてもらう ⇒ 言わ**し**てもらう
>   飲ませてもらう ⇒ 飲ま**し**てもらう
>   見せて ⇒ 見**し**て
>   させて ⇒ さ**し**て
>   やらせて ⇒ やら**し**て
>   etc.

In Kansai dialect we often use the short form of causative verbs, eg:

> 行かす (cf 行かせる)
>   食べさす (cf 食べさせる)
>   言わす (cf 言わせる)
>   飲ます (cf 飲ませる)
>   さす (cf させる)
>   やらす (cf やらせる)
>   etc.

Comment: Chocolateさん関西人やん？知らへんかった！ ホンマええやねん！

Comment: I feel like せ→し is quite common in Tokyo too, though it’s very casual (and possibly only among younger people?)

Comment: 私は @istrasci さん大阪に住んでたって覚えてるよ～　これ → https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38571/what-does-the-word-%e3%81%be%e3%81%8b%e3%81%9b%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8d-mean/38573#comment73467_38573