# What is the meaning of きいしません?

Tags: dialects, anime, kansai-ben

This is a sentence from *Digimon Adventure* episode 3. I don't understand the 「おそってはきいしませんで」 part.

It's also important to state that the character speaks a Japanese dialect.

> シードラモンは殺気を感じんかぎりおそってはきいしませんで

I interpret 「シードラモンは殺気を感じんかぎり」 as 「シードラモンは殺気を感じない限り」.

> As long as Seadramon does not feel the thirst for blood...

I tried to think of 「きい」 as a vowel extension of 「気」 and rendered it as "When it attacks, we don't care" but that doesn't really make sense because when someone attacks, you care, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [襲]{おそ}っては[来]{き}いしませんで

It means 襲ってはきませんよ.

Here in Kyoto, we sometimes say things like:

あらしません to mean ありません
わからしません to mean わかりません
かましまへん to mean かまいません
でけしまへん to mean できません
みいしまへん to mean みません

In the same way,

きいしません to mean きません

Comment: 未然形+「しない」、でしょうか？

Comment: 未然形＋「しません・しまへん」、ですね。あ、でも「[来]{き}い」は未然形じゃないなぁ・・

Comment: あ、「こない」は「きいひん」になるから「きいしません」になるのかな。「見ない」も「見いひん」「見いしまへん」って言うし。

Comment: @Chocolate さんは京都なんですかね。

Comment: はい、相変わらず京都にいますよ～！ @istrasci さんは大阪に住んでいたんですよね！　（ってこの問答すんの３回目やんなー）　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/69633/9831

Comment: そっかぁ  記憶力あまりよくないから... 

Comment: 京都では「こおへん」ということはないでしょうか（[こんなの](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1033506930)があったので)。自分は関東の人間ですが、関西弁というと何となく「きいひん」より「こおへん」をイメージしてました。

Comment: 大阪や神戸は「けえへん」「こおへん」って感じで、大阪の人は「きいひん」って言わないで、京都の人は「きいひん」って言いますが、京都って大阪の人もたくさん来るので、「こおへん」「けえへん」もよく聞きますし、近年だんだん大阪弁に近づいてきている気がします。同じように、京都は「しいひん」、大阪は「せえへん」ですが、京都でも「せえへん」って言う人が増えてる気がします。関西弁というと「きいひん」「しいひん」よりも「こおへん」「せえへん」をイメージするのは、京都弁より大阪弁の方が関西弁のスタンダードだから、まあ当然かなと思います。あと、「できひん」vs「でけへん」もありますね