# -てもろうとる is this Kansai Ben [volitional + continuous tense]

Tags: grammar, dialects, volitional-form, kansai-ben

The following dialogue is from *Rurouni Kenshin: The Beginning* so it is based in Kyoto:

> その狂った正義の先鋒…最も過酷な役割を務め**てもろうとる**

In Kansai I know

- **てまう**  [kansai] = **てしまう**   [tokyo]
- **とる** [kansai]  = ***ている** [tokyo]

So would this sentence then be:

> As the spearhead of this mad justice [that will bring this about]...  [he is having] the toughest role to serve

**Am I wrong because how can volitional tense and continuous tense co-exist ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 務めてもろうとる

It's Kansai-ben for 務めてもらっている. (務める+て+もらう+て+いる)

In Kansai-ben, people say...

> もろうて, もろて, (もうて) to mean もらって
> もろうた, もろた, (もうた) to mean もらった
> もろうとる, もろとる, もろてる, (もうとる, もうてる) to mean もらっている

Comment: 一応「もろとる」と「もうとる」もありますね。「もろうとる」が一番偽物っぽい感じがします。ところで、「〜とる」と「〜てる」はそれぞれ「おる{HL}」と「いる{HH}」のアクセントを踏襲していることに気づきました。

Comment: 「〜てもうてる」とか「〜てもうとる」と言うと、「〜てしまっている」の意味が強くなりますよね。「〜てもらっている」の意味なら、個人的には「〜てもらってる」と（ちゃんと）言うか「〜てもろてる」と言いますかね。

Comment: @Chocolateさんは関西人なの？

Comment: @istrasci 前にも京都人だとおっしゃいました。istrasciさんもご存じだとは思いましたが、お忘れなんでしょうか？

Comment: @istrasci 覚えてるでしょ　→ https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/98038/what-is-the-meaning-of-%e3%81%8d%e3%81%84%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93/98043#comment159437_98043  ＠Angelos ジョークでしょう 

Comment: @aguijonazo 私は京都弁（「京ことば」ではないですが）だからでしょうか、「てもらっている」も「てしまっている」も両方「てもうてる」て言ってます。（「てもらった」「てしまった」の両方に「てもうた」を使ってて、意味は文脈で判断‥「〇〇さんにやってもうた」みたいに。「もらって」も「もうて」と。「お父さんに開けてもうて。」とか。）大阪から来てる人は「もろてる」「もろた」って言ってる感じがします。関西弁のスタンダードは京都弁より大阪弁だと思うので、カッコに入れます。

Comment: @Angelos https://youtu.be/T_jNzapPvc0