# What does 観してもらう mean here?

Tags: grammar, dialects, kansai-ben

After watching a live performance by a certain actor, one fan was very impressed so she said

> DVDで観してもらいましたけど生の迫力パない

The live show was better than what is shown on DVD.

I don't understand what is meant by 観してもらいました here. Is it typo or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of 行かしてもらうから](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/69630/meaning-of-%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%8b%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%82%82%e3%82%89%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89), essentially みして→みせて

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a dialectical form of 観せてもらいました.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Didn't know it was a thing.