# What does the word 「やめにしい」 mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, manga, kansai-ben

Here is the dialogue containing the word.

> A: かってな推測はやめろう　おれは青山なんざ...
>
> B: 自分をごまかすのはいいかげんで**やめにしい**な　なんでもっときびしく現実をみつめようとはせんのや

Answer (score 4, accepted):

やめにしいな is a way of saying "stop!" in Kansai-ben.

- [`止め【やめ】 + に + する`](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%82%84%E3%82%81%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/) is a set phrase meaning "to cancel", "to stop", "to give up", "to quit", etc. Here its object is 自分をごまかすの ("deceiving yourself").
- しい (also written as しー, しぃ) is a Kansai-ben version of しろ. For example, 早くしろ/早くしな ("Hurry!") becomes はようしい. See: [What is the meaning of 「まちいな」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34604/5010)

> 自分をごまかすのはいいかげんでやめにしいな
>   Stop deceiving yourself already!

Comment: しい also has a regional variant せえ.

Comment: Is いい加減で an Osaka dialect? I thought いい加減に is correct.

Comment: @YuuichiTam I feel いい加減で is acceptable, although definitely less common. I don't know if its dialectal...

Comment: I have double checked. いいかげんで is really used in the manga.

Comment: @YuuichiTam 文法を考えると「いい加減にしろ」は「に」でいいですが「やめろ」には「で」でないと接続できないはずなので、これはむしろ慣用句になる前の原形に忠実な形ですよね。まあ個人的には何も付かない「いい加減」がここでは一番自然に聞こえますが…